# Core data Problem with Relationship in inheritance entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I have one Abstract Entity: Attachment, which has 2 simple attributes(UUID and String)

```
Attachment {
    id: UUID,
    type: String
}
```

And two inheritance models: FileAttachment and MessageAttachment.

File Attachment has one simple attribute link.

```
FileAttachment -> Attachment {
   link: URI
}
```

Message Attachment has one simple attribute text and one many relationship to Attachment attachments.

```
MessageAttachment -> Attachment {
     text: String
     attachments: [Attachment]
}
```

When I try to save file attachment model, it saves correctly.
When I try to save message attachment model, it saves not correct in most times.
But before calling context.save object of message attachment has correct data and after save, it has broken data mostly.
But if I moved relationship attachments from Message Attachment to Attachment(Abstract and Parent Entity) saving will be always okay.
When I looked database, which has created with core data and I found incorrect id in index-column(like zattachment).

Maybe it sounds very strange, but when I had similar situations, I always moved all relationships from inheritance entity to parent entities and after that saving was Okay.

Maybe you can explain this problem? Or maybe do I make mistakes?

Comment: Are you setting the attachments properly? Can you show the code on how are you creating the MessageAttachment?

Comment: For example I create FileAttachment object. Then I create MessageAttachment object and after initialisation I set attachments. messageAttachment.attachment = Set([fileAttachment]). And then I call context.save().

Comment: Can you change the line to messageAttachment.attachments.addAttachment(fileAttachment) and let me know the result?

Comment: When I tested I tried different ways, and it is no difference to use addAttachment and set attachments

Comment: Can you post photos of the zattachment and zmessageattachment? It is very difficult to see what's going wrong.